# Как изменять ссылку в кнопке при выборе select?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-form

Есть форма с селекторами

```
<form >
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <select class="selectpicker"  data-show-subtext="true" data-live-search="true">
                <option>Марка</option>
                <option>Audi</option>
                <option>BMW</option>
                <option>Chery</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <select class="selectpicker"  data-show-subtext="true" data-live-search="true">
                <option>Модель</option>
                <option>Первая модель</option>
                <option>Вторая модель</option>
                <option>Третья модель</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <select class="selectpicker"  data-show-subtext="true" data-live-search="true">
                <option>Поколение</option>
                <option>1990</option>
                <option>2005</option>
                <option>2019</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Перейти</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Как сделать так, что бы при выборе select в кнопку подставлялась определенная ссылка для перехода на страницу, которая будет формироваться основываясь на значении выбранных пунктов в select?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("button").on('click', function() {
  var mark = $("#mark option:selected").val();
  var model = $("#model option:selected").val();
  var age = $("#age option:selected").val();
  if(mark != 'Марка' && model != 'Модель' && age != 'Поколение') {
    // location.href = "http://localhost/?mark="+ mark + "&model="+ model +"&age="+ age;
    // или вариант в новом окне
    window.open("http://localhost/?mark="+ mark + "&model="+ model +"&age="+ age);

    console.log("http://localhost/?mark="+ mark + "&model="+ model +"&age="+ age);
  }
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="mark">
    <option>Марка</option>
    <option value="Audi">Audi</option>
    <option value="BMW">BMW</option>
    <option value="Chery">Chery</option>
</select>
<select id="model">
    <option>Модель</option>
    <option value="Первая модель">Первая модель</option>
    <option value="Вторая модель">Вторая модель</option>
    <option value="Третья модель">Третья модель</option>
</select>
<select id="age">
    <option>Поколение</option>
    <option value="1990">1990</option>
    <option value="2005">2005</option>
    <option value="2019">2019</option>
</select>
<button>Перейти</button>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, все работает, только не совсем понимаю, как правильно указать ссылку на страницу.  Мне нужно указывать такое название файла ?mark=Audi&model=Audi&age=Audi? Или как то можно указать какой ссылке будет равняться вариант?

Comment: как мне назвать файл? я не понимаю

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('form button[type="submit"]').click(function() {
    var params = {};
    $('form select[data-type]').each(function(index, element) {
        var select = $(this);
        params[select.data('type')] = select.val();
    });    
    
    var url = $.param(params);    
    alert(url);
    return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form >
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <select class="selectpicker" data-type="mark"  data-show-subtext="true" data-live-search="true">
                <option>Марка</option>
                <option>Audi</option>
                <option>BMW</option>
                <option>Chery</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <select class="selectpicker" data-type="model" data-show-subtext="true" data-live-search="true">
                <option>Модель</option>
                <option>Первая модель</option>
                <option>Вторая модель</option>
                <option>Третья модель</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <select class="selectpicker" data-type="age" data-show-subtext="true" data-live-search="true">
                <option>Поколение</option>
                <option>1990</option>
                <option>2005</option>
                <option>2019</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Перейти</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```